# Couldn't locate driver named mysql in doctrine php

Tags: php, doctrine, configuration-files

My application was working perfectly on localhost. But when i uploaded the application on server i got an error. I made a test file to check databse connection, this is the error i am getting. Please hellp me how to fix this..

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine_Connection_Exception' with message 'Couldn't locate driver named mysql' in /hermes/web05/b1392/moo.fanyer/httpdocs/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/Connection.php:492 Stack trace: #0 /hermes/web05/b1392/moo.fanyer/httpdocs/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/Connection/Mysql.php(101): Doctrine_Connection->connect() #1 /hermes/web05/b1392/moo.fanyer/httpdocs/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/Connection.php(1008): Doctrine_Connection_Mysql->connect() #2 /hermes/web05/b1392/moo.fanyer/httpdocs/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/Query/Abstract.php(1094): Doctrine_Connection->execute('SELECT u.id AS ...', Array) #3 /hermes/web05/b1392/moo.fanyer/httpdocs/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/Query/Abstract.php(1142): Doctrine_Query_Abstract->_execute(Array) #4 /hermes/web05/b1392/moo.fanyer/httpdocs/doctrine/models/Users.php(22): Doctrine_Query_Abstract->execute() #5 /hermes/web05/b1392/moo.fanyer/httpdocs/test.php(8): Users->get_details_username('mohit') #6 {main} thrown in /hermes/web05/b1392/moo.fanyer/httpdocs/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/Connection.php on line 492
```

Edit: how to enable my sql drivers..???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that:

- mysql extension is enabled on the server where you have uploaded files.
- you have specified the correct paths.
- there are no directory permission issues

Comment: you need to ask server support team where your site is going to be run.

Comment: It seems that the original developers may have been working on a work-around for the PDO dependency (which is where this error ACTUALLY gets thrown). If you inspect the source for Doctrine, file "Doctrine/Connection.php" lines 480-488 you will notice if the PDO failed to load, Doctrine tries to use a class named "Doctrine_Adapter_Mysql", but the only implemented adapter is for Oracle.

If you're like me, you don't have the option of installing PDO on the server (for various reasons), and unfortunately "phppdo" doesn't register as an "extension", so checks for "extension_loaded" will fail.

Answer (score 9):

apt-get install php5-mysql ---------------

Answer (score 8):

Enable pdo_mysql in the php.ini file